# omiting number sign using regex in java script not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I have written a simple code in a .js file (in Zend framework, but I dont think it matters)

```
var location = "localhost:8080/mymodule/id/1#";
location.replace(/\#/g, "");
alert(location.valueOf());
return;
```

but I dont know why I can not see the result I want.
I get my page url and want to omit all number signs appears in it. but the code above does nothing.
please help

Answer (score 6):

`location` is a bad name to use for a variable since it collides with the `window.location` variable used for the actual browser page location.

If you change `location` to `loc` in your above code, and then also add `loc =` in front of the `loc.replace()` call (since `replace()` doesn't modify the input, but instead returns the new version), your code works.

Answer (score 6):

`replace` will not change the value of the original string, you need to assign the result to a new variable -

```
var newString = location.replace(/#/g, "");
alert(newString);
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/5H5uZ/

Comment: Why are you escaping the `#`?

Comment: I'd just copied from the original question, removed now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done in one line. This is the result you look for?

```
alert("localhost:8080/mymodule/id/1#".replace(/#/g,'')); 
  //=> alerts 'localhost:8080/mymodule/id/1'
```